# Is it ok to have many functions (over 10) to handle the async nature of Node (especially when adding into MySql database)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-mysql

When I get an API call, i have to install to about 4,5 tables, since an entry has child items which in turn have child items. Since I have to pass data from the first insert to the second (using the parent ids) I end up having too many functions (like function insertTable1, insertTable1Kids, insertTable1KidsKids) so on..

Is this good design? It's bothering me that I'm using so many functions.. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use closures and the `async` module.

```
npm install async
```

Your code would look something like this...

```
var async = require('async');

exports.your_route = function(req, res) {
  var parent_id = req.query.parent_id;
  var calls = [];
  calls.push(function(callback) {
    // insertTable1 - use parent_id
    callback(false);
  });
  calls.push(function(callback) {
    // insertTable1Kids - use parent_id
    callback(false);
  });
  calls.push(function(callback) {
    // insertTable1KidsKids - use parent_id
    callback(false);
  });
  calls.push(function(callback) {
    // return response
    res.send("tabels for parent ID: "+parent_id+" created);
    callback(false);
  });
  async.series(calls);
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but how do i pass the data from one function to another?

Comment: If you need to pass data from one function to another then you would use the `async.waterfall` call.